# .NET Code Generated API endpoints from Data Access Classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

So say I've got a Data Access layer all built out and I don't care to hide the underlying core models from the API.

Is there a library or package that would allow me to tag specific data access classes and generate a WebAPI endpoint for each method based on a template? Or alternatively generate an entire API Controller?

Comment: I don't know a library, but you could do it fairly easily with a T4 template and some reflection.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490115/how-to-auto-generate-a-webapi-controller-for-mvc-entity-or-generically-query) maybe?

Comment: Perhaps have a look at odata: https://www.odata.org/