# Web API will not use ISerializable implementation

Tags: serialization, asp.net-web-api, json.net, swagger, swashbuckle

I thought I had jumped through the necessary hoops to get my `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` working with custom `ISerializable` implementations, complete with passing unit tests. But I'm unable to get it to work when I pass in values via Swagger UI.

**My key questions are:**

1. What am I doing wrong with my unit test causing it to serialize/deserialize different from what Web API is doing?
2. What do I need to change to get this working with Web API's serializing/deserialization and Swagger/Swashbuckle?

**Class being serialized:** (Notice that serializing and then deserializing drops off the time component and only keeps the date component. The helps for testing/observing purposes.)

```
public class Pet : ISerializable
{
    public DateTime Dob { get; set; }

    public Pet()
    {
        Dob = DateTime.Parse("1500-12-25 07:59:59");
    }

    public Pet(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Dob = DateTime.Parse(info.GetString("Dob"));
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("Dob", Dob.Date.ToString());
    }
}
```

**Web API Method:** (always returns null)

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [Route("~/api/Pet")]
    public string Get([FromUri] Pet data)
    {
        return data.Dob.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Passing Unit Test:** (and serialization helpers [from MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization) docs)

```
[TestFixture]
public class SerializationTests
{
    [Test]
    public void PetTest()
    {
        var date = new DateTime(2017, 1, 20, 5, 0, 0);
        var foo = new Pet { Dob = date };

        var jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter { SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver { IgnoreSerializableInterface = false } } };
        var serialized = SerializationHelpers.Serialize(jsonFormatter, foo);

        Console.WriteLine(serialized);
        var deserialized = SerializationHelpers.Deserialize<Pet>(jsonFormatter, serialized);

        Assert.That(foo.Dob, Is.Not.EqualTo(date.Date));
        Assert.That(deserialized.Dob, Is.EqualTo(date.Date));
    }
}

public static class SerializationHelpers
{
    public static string Serialize<T>(MediaTypeFormatter formatter, T value)
    {
        // Create a dummy HTTP Content.
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        var content = new StreamContent(stream);
        // Serialize the object.
        formatter.WriteToStreamAsync(typeof(T), value, stream, content, null).Wait();
        // Read the serialized string.
        stream.Position = 0;
        return content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(MediaTypeFormatter formatter, string str) where T : class
    {
        // Write the serialized string to a memory stream.
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(str);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        // Deserialize to an object of type T
        return formatter.ReadFromStreamAsync(typeof(T), stream, null, null).Result as T;
    }
}
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.Formatters.Clear();
        var jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter { SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver { IgnoreSerializableInterface = false } } };
        config.Formatters.Add(jsonFormatter);

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**A few other notes:**

1. When I run the passing unit test, the `Console.WriteLine` output is:

> {"Dob":"1/20/2017 12:00:00 AM"}

which is exactly what I want/expect.

2. My Swagger UI looks like this using the default Swashbuckle settings from Nuget. Note that value of the date is what is set in the default constructor, showing that my `ISerializable` implementation is ignored.

[image: Basic Deserialization Results]

**NOTE:**
I have changed the question to remove all generics from the picture. This problem is fundamentally about `ISerializable` implementations now and not about Generics.

Comment: I think the issue here is with the use of generics on your GET request model - `public string Get([FromUri] MyClass<PersonDto> data)`. MyClass model cannot be a generic. Try making that parameter a concrete type.

Comment: @alltej I can definitely get simple POCO classes to serialize correctly. Why are generics a problem? I have tried using a custom `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` (which works in unit tests) but the exactly same `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` fails when Web API invokes it. Why can I not leverage my custom-defined serialization? All of the blogs and MSDN docs say I can use custom serialization.

Answer (score 0):

WebAPI api does not know how to deserialize this generic object. I see a similar question here in SO but did not personally try/test it. Hope it helps: [Generic Web Api method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29398241/generic-web-api-method)

Rather than having a generic method, you can create a generic controller. So your code above will look something like below.

```
public abstract class MyClass{ }

public class PersonDto: MyClass{}


public class TestController<T> : ApiController where T: MyClass
{
    public string Get([FromUri] T data)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on your input, I have found that I can simplify the problem. I have edited the question heavily and now generics are now longer part of the problem. The problem is completely about Web API and `ISerializable` implementations. This should confirm that generics are not the fundamental problem here.