# webapi 2 controller get method requesting\returning a generic type from Angular?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I'm getting a little confused and my OO / Model binding knowledge isn't what it should be. I have created a repository that can return a List of Typed objects based on a generic Type.

```
public RawDataAggregatedItems<Project> Get(int? id)
        {
            return _uiDataClass.GetRawDataAggregated<Project>(id);
        }

return _uiDataClass.GetRawDataAggregated<AssetType>(periodId);
return _uiDataClass.GetRawDataAggregated<Category>(periodId);
....
```

Rather than have 3 separate Get methods in my WebApi Controller referring to each Type I thought I would refactor and pass in a generic Type T.

return _uiDataClass.GetRawDataAggregated(periodId);

```
    [HttpGet]
    public RawDataAggregatedItems<T> Get<T>(int? periodId)
        where T : RawDataAggregatedItem, new()
    {
        return _uiDataClass.GetRawDataAggregated<T>(periodId);
    }

    or

    [HttpPost]
    public RawDataAggregatedItems<T> Get<T>(RawDataAggregateViewModel viewModel)
        where T : RawDataAggregatedItem, new()
    {
        return _uiDataClass.GetRawDataAggregated<T>(viewModel.PeriodId);
    }
```

**How do i call this from Angular and tell it which Type I want?** A complicating factor maybe that all the derived Types of RawDataAggregatedItem have the same set of properties, just different values.

```
 return $http({ method: "GET", url: "/api/RawDataAggregated/Project/" + periodId });

 return $http({
            method: "POST", url: "/api/RawDataAggregated/",
            data:
            {
                AggregateType: aggregateBy,
                PeriodId: periodId
            }
        });
```

I'm getting server responses of 500 what ever i do.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is this working if you just past the url in the browser? I don't think this is an Angular issue - how do your routes look to support generic controllers? Here's what someone else did and might work for you too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023793/generic-web-api-controller .

Comment: default routes. The alternative you have posted is similar to providing 3 separate Controller methods, but at controller level. I was trying to get to one controller, one web method. Could be a step too far...

Comment: Yeah, that's probably not going to work .. unless my web api knowledge is a bit out of date. That route has no way of knowing what type to use for the controller. Use what's in the link I gave above and then your life will be a lot simpler

Answer (score 1):

You may achive that via some play with Reflection. You already passing actual data type to the server, now you have to find actual type and call your method specifying actual type. It may look like the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public RawDataAggregatedItems<T> Get<T>(RawDataAggregateViewModel viewModel)
{
    //Finding required type
    var actualType=Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(x => x.Name == viewModel.AggregateType).FirstOrDefault();

    //Constructing generic method
    MethodInfo theMethod = entity.GetType().GetMethod("GetRawDataAggregated");
    MethodInfo generic =  theMethod.MakeGenericMethod(actualType);
    return generic.Invoke(_uiDataClass, new object[] { viewModel.periodId})
}
```