# To Create Action That Accepts a Parameter Of Any Type Derived From The Parameter Type (Polymorphic Parameter)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, parametric-polymorphism

I want to build a dynamic structure for a client to ask server in web API. I have tried to use the following code to deal with my question, however, it isn't working.

> 1. How can I send a generic type like `<travel>` to service
> 2. How can I change server code (or all need to change client/server)?

PS:Thank you for your patience if you have read my question to the end.

Client Code

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();    
var product = new travel() { travel_desc = "select * from travel" };    
var jsonText = serializer.Serialize(product);    
var client = new HttpClient();    
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:65370/");     
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));    
StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonText, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");     

var z = client.PostAsync<travel>("api/bb", product, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()).Result;
```

Server Code, which is not working

```
public IHttpActionResult Post< T > (Object x) where T : new()    
{    
                ........................    
}
```

by the way it is okay but i don't know how to send < T > to server

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(Object x)    
{    
                ........................    
}
```

Error message
`Client call server, server will be getting an error message " StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found' "`

```
 var z = client.PostAsync < travel > ("api/dd", product, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()).Result; <--client

    public class ddController< T > : ApiController {public virtual void Post() {   ... }  } <---server    





  // sorry all , my English isn't very well , so I will try to use code to tell everyone how i want 
// in format situations,I will create 2 controller when I have 2 models(ex: users/product) , as following (client)
                var a = client.PostAsync("api/users", users, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()).Result;
                var b = client.PostAsync("api/product", product, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()).Result;

//and then when the users and product controllers was created the post code should be like as following (server)
                public IHttpActionResult Postusers(users travel) {}
                public IHttpActionResult Postproduct(product travel) {}

   //now i just want to create 1 controller for above  like as follwing 
                 var b = client.PostAsync<users/product>("api/all", product, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()).Result;(client)

                 public IHttpActionResult Post<T>(Object ForAll) where T : new() {} (server)
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077361/generic-webapi-controller

Comment: Hi Kamo Client can not triggle server POST event

Comment: Hi   Konamiman : it isn't work in my case , do you have other ways to do it ,thanks

Comment: Hi @Konamiman  , sorry to bother you , I didn't use Stack Overflow for a long time , but now I cannot send any Ask Question  , I don't know what can I do , because I have tried modifies all my questions , but "Ask Question" isn't work, so that I wise someone who can help me , sorry again , and hopefully you can do me a favor , thanks , Willie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON.NET, the Web API JSON serializer, is able to send type information when serializing an object, and use that same information to deserialize it.

The trick that it uses is including a `$type` property as the first property of the JSON object.

If you want to use this technique, you need to have a base class or an interface, for example `ITravel`, inherit all the possible classes from it, and use the base class or interface as the parameter type, like so:

```
public interface ITravel
{
  public int TravelId { get; set; }
}

public class TravelTypeA : ITravel
{
  public int TravelId { get; set; }
  public string Destination { get; set; }
}

public class TravelTypeB : ITravel
{
  ...
}

[HttpPost]
public object PostMeATravel(ITravel travel)
{
    // check what type is travel with "is" or ".GetType()"
}
```

You also need to instruct JSON to include type information when (de)serializing `ITravel` objects. ([JSON TypeName Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638741/deserialising-json-to-derived-types-in-asp-net-web-api/23999085#23999085)):

```
JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings 
  = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters
    .JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;

serializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
```

And then you have to post a JSON with typeInformation, like this:

```
{
  $type: 'SampleApp.TravelTypeA, SampleApp',
  TravelId: 22,
  Destination: 'La Almunia de Doña Godina'
}
```

When you do so, JSON.NET will use the type information to create a `TravelTypeA` object, and pass it as parameter to the action, which expects an `ITravel`. Inside the action you can check the type of the received parameter if you need to do so, like this: `if (travel.GetType().Name == "TravelTypeA") { ... }`

Look at this Q&A for more information on how to do that, how it works, and advantages and drawbacks of this method and an alternative way of doing it: [Deserialising Json to derived types in Asp.Net Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638741/deserialising-json-to-derived-types-in-asp-net-web-api/23999085#23999085)

*NOTE: you can use the excellent Postman complement for Chrome to test the Web API methods*

Comment: Hi JB , would you mind give me a short sample include client/server site, I will be thanking you to do this for me , thanks again

Comment: I  the referenced Q&A you've got enough information: add the JSON.NET configuration to any bootstrap class, of the AppStart folder. Create a controller, an interface and two classes like the ones I show in this answer. And finally, make a POST request to this controller, with the properties od `TravelTypeA` and adding the `$type: MyNamespace.TravelTypeA, MyAsssemblyName` (fully qualified type name) as the first property of teh JSON object. Your POST action will receive an instance of TravelTypeA.If you have some concrete problem implementing this, let me know it. Test it with chrome's postman

Comment: Hi JB, maybe it is too difficult for me , could you help me to give me more reference urls,  because i have tried as above you give me references to my code , "public class TravelTypeA : ITravel {}" <-- could you tell me how to setup it ,give me a short example , thanks ,Willie

Comment: I've added a little more info in my answer. Please, look at it

Comment: JB.really thankyou for your help, I was put another code behind my context , would you mind see it again , sorry for my stupid English, maybe I didn't descript my question very clear for you , can you understand what my question is ,or in fact I have solved my problem on your content , if yes , I will be trying it more times , it is very hard to me. thanks again for your kindness