# How can i pass generic type from view to controller

Tags: c#, generics, model-view-controller

I want my MVC View send a type to action result as parameter so that i could use that type in my generic class

```
    public ActionResult ManageData(T genericType) 
    {
        var result = new BaseData<genericType>().GetSharedData();
        return View(result);
    }
```

Comment: Did you mean `new BaseData<T>()`?

Comment: @Sweeper: I think he means  `public ActionResult ManageData(Type genericType) `

Comment: @Sweeper BaseData<T> can get different types, and i want get these types from view

Comment: this doesn't make sense as its the same same as object, you are trying to use the construct wrong.`public ActionResult ManageData(object objThing) `

Comment: where as if you returned it as said thing it would make more sense `public 
BaseData<someType>() ManageData("some in data if needed")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have generic controller methods. I'm not sure whats your use-case but you could do something like this

```
public ActionResult ManageData(string type) 
{
    switch (type) {
        case 'first':
            return View(new BaseData<FirstType>().GetSharedData());
        case 'second':
            return View(new BaseData<SecondType>().GetSharedData());
        default:
            return View();
    }
}
```

Of couse you could improve this by moving your `switch` to some kind of `BaseDataFactory` or use `string enums` instead of pure `strings` for  easier and more readable `string` -> `type` mapping.

Comment: it is possible to have generic controllers and thus methods as well, see [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3418849/5519026), [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57746572/5519026)

Comment: Those are generic controllers that can be used as base classes and therefore generic type is resolved in compile time and that is not what he is asking for. You can't have generic method on which you pass generic argument dinamically from the client and as far as I understood, he wants that behaviour.

Comment: @LazZiya Please see above.