# Entity Framework Core & APS .NET core: create a flexible API that allows you to tell it what to include

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to create an API using EF Core and ASP .NET Core that is flexible and allows you to eager load?

For example: you would call **groups** with a post call and you could ***tell*** the API *"include the users list in those loaded entities"*.

Also it would be nice to pass conditions to the API.

Do you have to create specific methods for this like `LoadGroups` for groups and `LoadGroupsWithUsers` for a include of users or is it possible to create a single method in the Controller for this that is capable of handling both?

Comment: It is not clear enough what you want to achieve, is it generic api methods? if so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57696575/generic-methods-for-api-controller/57746572#57746572) may help you

Comment: Are you not bleeding with your UI to the back end coupling them together at this point? You would probably need to create your own extension method to do this otherwise or bunch of "if" statements or get everything and do a custom mapping to the DTO object. You could try and explore graphQL for this if I correctly understood you https://fullstackmark.com/post/17/building-a-graphql-api-with-aspnet-core-2-and-entity-framework-core

Comment: what have you tried and why do you think it wont work or wouldn't be possible, what is it that you are worried about. Yes its possible, but you would need to engineer it. basically design your contract as the means to to " tell it what to include".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @vsarunov mentioned this can be achieved by using GraphQL.
Here his [link](https://fullstackmark.com/post/17/building-a-graphql-api-with-aspnet-core-2-and-entity-framework-core).