# How to create model based REST API endpoints in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am looking for a way to make REST API endpoints based on models, I know that this is possible within Django. But I haven't found a similar way to do this in asp.net core, is there any framework for this platform that provides this functionality?

How it works in django when you use the djangorestframework:

Define a model, auto migrate everything:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

That model is used to create an endpoint. A Serializer decides which fields are shown:

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude = ()
```

A viewset for the ORM Query:

```
class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
```

And some routermapping:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'persons', PersonViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

And now I have an API that can

1. GET /person - list all persons
2. GET /person/1 - give details of a specific person
3. POST /person - create a person
4. PUT /person/1 - update a person
5. DELETE /person/1 - delete a person

Is there anything similar in asp.net core?

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. I'll keep my eyes on this one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at `generic controllers`, see e.g.:

- [Generic Web Api controller to support any model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077361/generic-web-api-controller-to-support-any-model)
- [Generic and dynamically generated controllers in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://www.strathweb.com/2018/04/generic-and-dynamically-generated-controllers-in-asp-net-core-mvc/)
- [ASP.NET Core - Generic web API controller with generic repository pattern](https://gist.github.com/matjazmav/d0c5f5afc600a50b7de8630aa2d11a61)

Comment: Aye, but there is no framework or such that has this altogether as in out of the box?
I was building it myself but I was thinking "Surely someone did this" but doesnt seem to be the case.

Comment: Unfortunately not that I am aware of. It probably is too easy to generate controllers :).

Comment: @user7217806 Why don't we just write everything in assembler, I mean everything is too easy if you think about it, right?

Comment: @Sem Please note the smiley, I am of course not being serious about this statement.

Comment: Accepted this as the answer, I bascially made my own Framework to facilitate this, with the help of above information, see: https://github.com/oxidda/leatherback